# Trouble getting OTL connecting to MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, odbc, otl

I am trying to use OTL to avoid the GPL on MyODBC (and because it is very nice).  It compiles fine but I get a

> "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified"

error on the console.  This code isn't mine and you can get it in several places online.  Can someone help?

**Fixed: I had to specify a DSN driver name and I thought it was asking me for the TCP info.  Sorry guys...**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define OTL_ODBC // Compile OTL 4.0/ODBC
// The following #define is required with MyODBC 3.51.11 and higher
#define OTL_ODBC_SELECT_STM_EXECUTE_BEFORE_DESCRIBE
// #define OTL_ODBC_UNIX // uncomment this line if UnixODBC is used
#include "otlv4.h" // include the OTL 4.0 header file

otl_connect db; // connect object

void insert()
// insert rows into table
{
otl_stream o(1, // buffer size should be == 1 always on INSERT
"insert into test_tab values "
" (:f1<int>,:f2<char[31]>), "
" (:f12<int>,:f22<char[31]>), "
" (:f13<int>,:f23<char[31]>), "
" (:f14<int>,:f24<char[31]>), "
" (:f15<int>,:f25<char[31]>) ",
// INSERT statement. Multiple sets of values can be used
// to work around the lack of the bulk interface
db // connect object
);

// If the number of rows to be inserted is not known in advance,
// another stream with the same INSERT can be opened
otl_stream o2(1, // buffer size should be == 1 always on INSERT
"insert into test_tab values "
" (:f1<int>,:f2<char[31]>)",
db // connect object
);

char tmp[32];
int i;
for(i=1;i<=100;++i){
sprintf(tmp,"Name%d",i);
o<<i<<tmp;
}
for(i=101;i<=103;++i){
sprintf(tmp,"Name%d",i);
o2<<i<<tmp;
}
}

void update(const int af1)
// insert rows into table
{
otl_stream o(1, // buffer size should be == 1 always on UPDATE
"UPDATE test_tab "
"   SET f2=:f2<char[31]> "
" WHERE f1=:f1<int>",
// UPDATE statement
db // connect object
);
o<<"Name changed"<<af1;
o<<otl_null()<<af1+1; // set f2 to NULL

}

void select(const int af1)
{
otl_stream i(50, // buffer size may be > 1
"select * from test_tab "
"where f1>=:f11<int> "
"  and f1<=:f12<int>*2",
// SELECT statement
db // connect object
);
// create select stream

int f1;
char f2[31];

i<<af1<<af1; // :f11 = af1, :f12 = af1
while(!i.eof()){ // while not end-of-data
i>>f1;
cout<<"f1="<<f1<<", f2=";
i>>f2;
if(i.is_null())
cout<<"NULL";
else
cout<<f2;
cout<<endl;
}

}

int main()
{
otl_connect::otl_initialize(); // initialize ODBC environment
try{


db.rlogon("root/orbit12@mysql3306");
//db.rlogon("UID=scott;PWD=tiger;DSN=mysql35"); // connect to ODBC
//  db.rlogon("scott/tiger@mysql35"); // connect to ODBC, alternative format
// of connect string

otl_cursor::direct_exec
(
db,
"drop table test_tab",
otl_exception::disabled // disable OTL exceptions
); // drop table

otl_cursor::direct_exec
(
db,
"create table test_tab(f1 int, f2 varchar(30))"
//"create table test_tab(f1 int, f2 varchar(30)) type=innoDB" (causes MYSQL error)
);  // create table

insert(); // insert records into the table
update(10); // update records in the table
select(8); // select records from the table

}

catch(otl_exception& p){ // intercept OTL exceptions
cerr<<p.msg<<endl; // print out error message
cerr<<p.stm_text<<endl; // print out SQL that caused the error
cerr<<p.sqlstate<<endl; // print out SQLSTATE message
cerr<<p.var_info<<endl; // print out the variable that caused the error
}

db.logoff(); // disconnect from ODBC

return 0;

}
```

Comment: having this issue too ... i tried specifying a dsn con_.rlogon("user/pass@localhost"); and still no go

Comment: TELL ME HOW YOU DID IT